# camera1394 and bumblebee2

Tags: ros, camera1394, bumblebee, stereo, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am new to ROS and am currently working on getting the Bumblebee2 node (By Soonhac Hong, source: http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bumblebee2) to work properly in Ubuntu 10.10 for my Pt grey Bumblebee2 stereo camera.

After resolving some preliminary issues, I continue to receive the same error message whenever I launch Bumblebee2.launch:

"

FATAL 1298844152.453260264: [camera] exception opening device: [Camera1394::open]: No cameras found

"

The node appears in rxgraph.

So I thought to myself "maybe the camera1394 node will work properly?" (I have no experience with this node, so that's just a wild guess) and a tried launching camera.launch from the test folder. I received the following messages:

"

ERROR 1298842394.512674033: [camera] device open failed: [Camera1394::open]: No cameras found
ERROR 1298842394.512964522: Unable to open camera calibration file [/cameras/unibrain_calibration.yaml]

"

I also tried launching stereo_example.launch:

"
error loading  tag:

file does not exist [/cameras/unibrain.yaml]

XML is rosparam file="/cameras/unibrain.yaml"/
"

I have attempted to use the camera using coriander and kino... they both cannot find a camera connected to the bus. I have already troubleshooted common bus permissions issues as per http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/Troubleshooting#No_Bus_Access_Permissions. The camera works in a Windows environment.

Any ideas how I can get this thing working???

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9222/camera1394-and-bumblebee2/) by [rob-bot](https://answers.ros.org/users/185/rob-bot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an Ubuntu problem, not a ROS problem, until you solve the bus access problem. No ROS driver is going to work if `coriander` cannot find the device.

The `camera1394` driver does not support Bumblebee or any other interlaced stereo devices. Perhaps it will in some future release (see [enhancement ticket #4782](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4782)).

Note that all the launch files in the `camera1394` package tests directory are marked "this is a test script: NOT FOR GENERAL USE". You can construct your own launch files based on those examples, but should not expect them to work unmodified.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2